# Using mains in a project with just a power cable (ground wire)

Tags: ground, mains, neutral

I'm going to power a 235 V band heater with a computer power cable (has fuse, SSR and thermocouple, too.) Everything is enclosed within a box, and there are no open junctions etc. I am unsure what to use the ground wire of the mains for.

Should I attach it to the metal band heater just in case a short circuit somehow happens and the barrel/heater becomes electrified?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend earthing / grounding the heater band protective cover to prevent nasty surprises should you have to open the box to service it.